How could I formally express: System F cannot express universal quantification over things that are not types?
I'm trying to understand exactly why it is that https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/computational+trilogy states that quantification requires dependent types, and why this wouldn't be possible to achieve with System F. From what I've managed to gather, System F can express quantification, but only over types, and not over elements or predicates.
I'm looking for a way to formalize this statement in order to start working on a proof. How could I express: System F lacks the expressive power to state quantification over terms? Or, lacks the expressive power to state quantification in the way made possible by dependent types?

cross-posted from mathover and math stackexchange

Do not cross-post, it's impolite. Pick one site and delete the other two. Also, in order to speak of quantification over terms, you first need to explain what a predicate/type on terms is supposed to be in System F, so that we can then quantify over them.

@AndrejBauer sorry!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4968748/how-could-i-formally-express-system-f-cannot-express-universal-quantification-o and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/478414/how-could-i-formally-express-system-f-cannot-express-universal-quantification-o
